# No events in Google Chrome from SVG elements referenced by use tag

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, svg, dom-events

In the Chrome version "54.0.2840" (Windows 7 and 8.1, current version as of 2016-10-31) events were not fired from `<use>` tag. It worked in v53 and it works in current Firefox and IE versions. Here is example code:

```
<body>
<svg>
  <defs>
    <g id="foo">
      <rect x="0" y="0" width="50" height="50" fill="red" onclick="alert('b')"></rect>
    </g>
  </defs>
</svg>
<svg width="100" height="100">
  <use xlink:href="#foo"></use>
  <rect x="50" y="0" width="50" height="50" fill="blue" onclick="alert('a')"></rect>
</svg>
</body>
```

And a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vinterros/kgrm2mjp/)

In the above code, running with Firefox both the alert (a) and (b) are showing, but in Chrome only (a) is showing.

My questions are:

- Is it bad practice to capture events like this?
- Any suggestions on how to work around the issue?

I need the specific event element from the "foo" group so capturing a click on the "use" tag would not be sufficient.

The problem is described in [this post](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-discuss/ztHDSzI-Gdg) (not by me). I didn't find it reported in the bug tracker.

**Update**
Apparently the behavior is intended for now because of security reasons (see link to bug report in the answer).

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same problem since the latest update too.

I have posted a bug to Chromium for this issue using your jsfiddle:

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=667324

Please star it so it attracts attention.

(Would have commented on your question but I don't have the karma) :-(